# QBO Queries and SpecifyOperatorOption

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to query QBO for, among other entities, Accounts, and am running into a couple of issues. I'm using the .Net Dev Kit v 2.1.10.0 (I used NuGet to update to the latest version) and when I use the following technique:

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery cquery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery();
IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account> qboAccounts =     cquery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>(context);
```

(i.e. just create a new AccountQuery of the appropriate type and call ExecuteQuery) I get an error. It seems that the request XML is not created properly, I just see one line in the XML file. I then looked at the online docs and tried to emulate the code there:

```
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery cquery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery();
        cquery.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-20);

        cquery.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.CreateTime,
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterOperatorType.AFTER);

        cquery.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
        cquery.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.CreateTime,
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterOperatorType.BEFORE);
        // Specify a Request validator
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery cquery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery();
        IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account> qboAccounts = cquery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>(context);
```

unfortunately, VS 2010 insists that AccountQuery doesn't contain a definition for SpecifyOperatorOption and there is no extension method by that name. So I'm stuck.

Any ideas how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the XML that it's generating and sending out? https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=69&threadid=18002&enterthread=y

Comment: OK, as usual, after leaving the message and scouring the SDK docs I figured I had to add the Intuit.Ipp.Data.Extensions namespace. That corrected the compiler error but of course it would have been nice to know that you HAVE to supply a filter of some sort or the .Net DevKit bombs when creating the XML. Keith-just saw your post, here's the request when you don't supply a filter: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string />. That's right, just that one line.